# Item not found even after the trait is defined and implemented

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am following a [CLI tutorial](https://rust-cli.github.io/book/tutorial/cli-args.html) and
The main code looks like this:

```
#![allow(unused)]

use clap::Parser;

/// Search for a pattern in a file and display the lines that contain it.
#[derive(Parser)]
struct Cli {
    /// The pattern to look for
    pattern: String,
    /// The path to the file to read
    path: std::path::PathBuf,
}


fn main() {
    let args = Cli::parse();
}
```

On running the code above, gives the below error.

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `parse` found for struct `Cli` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:16:21
   |
7  | struct Cli {
   | ---------- function or associated item `parse` not found for this struct
...
16 |     let args = Cli::parse();
   |                     ^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Cli`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following traits define an item `parse`, perhaps you need to implement one of them:
           candidate #1: `Parser`
           candidate #2: `TypedValueParser`
```

The `parse()` is an item associated with the trait `Clap::Parser()`which was derived to the `struct Cli` and yet the compiler fails to recognize the implementation. Any ways around this?

Comment: Can you please share a [mre] the code you posted [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d653dfeb67c8e608071313f508191e71)

Comment: Did you add the derive feature for clap?